# Erro em dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que há de errado com este dicionário?

```
Dados = {'Alunos': {
    {'Nome': 'Jon', 'Notas':[8,9,6]},
    {'Nome': 'Giglio', 'Notas':[7,6,5]},
    {'Nome': 'Antony', 'Notas':[5,6,9]}
    }
}

for nome, info in Dados.items():
    print(nome, info)
```

Erro retornado:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Preciso criar Mais um FOR dentro do primeiro FOR ??

Comment: Dicionário não pode ser chave pra outro.

Comment: Como na minha resposta? Ou outra forma?

Answer (score 9):

Um `dicionário` não pode ser `chave` de outro dicionário pois a chave deve ser um `objeto imutável`, além do mais é mais lógico definir os alunos como uma lista da seguinte forma:

```
dados = {'Alunos': [
    {'Nome': 'Jon', 'Notas':[8,9,6]},
    {'Nome': 'Giglio', 'Notas':[7,6,5]},
    {'Nome': 'Antony', 'Notas':[5,6,9]}
]}

for aluno in dados['Alunos']:
    for nome, notas in aluno.items():
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o que você pretende criar é **uma lista de alunos dentro de um dicionário**. Houve um pequeno erro no seu código.

Você tem o dicionário `Dados` com o item `Alunos` que guarda uma lista de alunos dentro dele, sendo que cada aluno é formado por um dicionário com as chaves `Nome` e `Notas`.

Logo, a lógica é uma lista de dicionários dentro de outro dicionário:

```
Dados = {'Alunos': [ # o erro aconteceu neste ponto quanto você colocou { ao invés de [
    {'Nome': 'Jon', 'Notas':[8,9,6]},    # primeiro aluno da lista
    {'Nome': 'Giglio', 'Notas':[7,6,5]}, # segundo aluno da lista
    {'Nome': 'Antony', 'Notas':[5,6,9]}  # terceiro aluno da lista
]}
```

Para percorrer os alunos e exibir os dados deles, você primeiro precisa entrar na chave `Alunos` do dicionário `Dados`:

```
for aluno in Dados['Alunos']: # para cada aluno
    print(aluno['Nome'], aluno['Notas']) # mostre o nome e nota
```